# How to use different forms in a view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm new in django and have a question about how to use the views in a situation:

I have a view which loads a track file.The track is broken down by different ways and I want to show every one, one by one, in a map. the user has to fill in a form with characteristics of the way. When one ends, I want to load the next until its finishes. I'm not sure about the structure that I have to use for this situation.

```
def acoplar_track(request, track_id):     
    track = get_object_or_404(Track, id=track_id) 
    x=Xarxa(track.zona.nom) #an object from a custom library
    ...
    #split the track in different ways
    ...
    newWays = x.getTrackWays(); # a list with the ways ids

    for way in newWays:            
        emplenarWay(wId,x) #Function that have to show the way in a map and alow the user to fill the form.

    return render_to_response('principal/inici.html', context_instance = RequestContext(request)) #final template


def carregar_way(request, x, way_id):

    if request.method=='POST':
        formulari = WayForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formulari.is_valid():   
            x.processData(formulari.descripcio, formulari.tipus)

            # something for render de form again or come back to the loop of the previous function... NO IDEA!!   

    else:
        formulari = WayForm()
        mapFeatures = x.getMapFeatures(way_id)

    return render(request,'principal/WayForm.html',
    {'formulari':formulari, 'mapFeatures'=mapFeatures})
```

forms.py

```
CHOICES = (('1','Pista',),('2','Corriol',))             
class WayForm(forms.Form):
    descripcio = forms.Textarea()
    tipus = forms.ChoiceField(        
        widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES)
```

It could be something like this?

Comment: It's a little difficult to understanding what you're looking for.  Am I right in assuming that you want to have users fill out the same set of form fields, multiple times, having an empty (new) form load when the user finishes the previous one?  If you indeed want the **same** set of form fields to be filled out multiple times, check out Formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: I want something like that moreless. I need to show the form as meny times as ways has the track. But I don't only need to show the form again, I need to render another html page with the from and the map that shows this part of the track. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that you want to show a common form (the same fields each time) and a different image of the track someone is following. I'd start by defining the [form class object.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/) Then create two templates, one is the base where you cycle over the form fields for display purposes, the second is for your images and you extend from the base template. Then in your view, you are either displaying data to your templates (the base form and the specific track image) or you are processing the form data and moving the user to the next part of the track. See [forms in views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) for great information on how to process forms in a view. Use your render_to_response and the ID of your track map to setup the next page to render.

Comment: I don't want to load an image, the map is done with javascript using the vairables that I pass from the view to the template and is executed with the tag <body onload="init()">. This variables change for every way. What you say could be useful to me, but I can't uderstand you. What I have to do in the view for load the form diferent times? When I finish the first form, I don't know how to pass to the next... I've added more information in the question. Thanks!